# Multiple Joins of one to many relationships

Tags: sql, join, filemaker

I have a FMP database that I'd like to query with SQL.
I'm trying to query 3 or more tables at a time.

The table structure is as follows:

```
##########      ###############
#  USER  # -->  #   PROJECTS  #
##########      ###############

     |          ###########
     ---->      # SAMPLES #
     |          ###########
     |
     |          #####################
     ---->      # PROCESSED_SAMPLES #
                #####################
```

They are all linked by a user_id.

USER contains a lot of fields, but the important ones in this case are:

- Progress
- Status

Each user can be under multiple PROJECTS, and can have multiple SAMPLES and PROCESSED SAMPLES. Each sample has a DATE, and VISIT_STATUS. Each processed sample has fields DATE, ORIGIN and LEVEL

The queries I've been trying to figure out are (in not actual SQL):

```
> SELECT STATUS, count(num of USERS) FROM (tables) WHERE project = X AND LEVEL >= 1 GROUP BY STATUS

> SELECT STATUS, count(num of USERS) FROM (tables) WHERE project = X AND LEVEL >= 1 AND ORIGIN = Y

> SELECT STATUS, count(num of USERS) FROM (tables) WHERE project = X AND LEVEL >= 1 AND ORIGIN = Y AND (processed sample.DATE = sample.DATE AND sample.VISIT_STATUS = Z)
```

I'm trying to find number of USERS with in each different status that are working under a specific project that have a processed sample from a specific origin that have level >= 1.

Queries going through two tables like the following query work. But I've been unsuccessful doing any sort of JOIN with more than two tables.

```
SELECT STATUS, count(STATUS) as c
FROM 
     USER A
     JOIN
     PROJECTS B
     on A.user_id = B.user_id
WHERE B.project = X
GROUP BY STATUS
ORDER BY c DESC
```

I have not been successful with something like this:

```
SELECT STATUS, count(STATUS) as c
FROM 
     USER A
     JOIN
     PROJECTS B
     on A.user_id = B.user_id
     JOIN
     PROCESSED SAMPLES C
     on B.user_id  = C.user_id
WHERE B.project = X C.LEVEL >= 1
GROUP BY STATUS
ORDER BY c DESC
```

I'm not entirely sure if this table structure lets me do joins like this. Another way I have attempted is:

```
SELECT STATUS, count(STATUS) as c
FROM
     USER A
     JOIN
     PROJECTS B
     on A.user_id = B.user_id
     JOIN
        ( SELECT user_id, sum(CASE WHEN LEVEL >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) as s
          FROM PROCESSED_SAMPLES
          GROUP BY user_id ) AS C
     on B.user_id = C.user_id
WHERE B.project = X AND C.s > 0
GROUP BY STATUS
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Which also didn't seem to work. And since I'm going through FMP, if I have a error in my query, I get this super useful '?' returned. While I'd prefer not alter table structure drastically, I have full liberty to add more fields to the tables.

Thanks!

Comment: Is Processed Samples meant to be two words? I can't tell what type of sql you are using but most variations either don't allow multiword table names or require some sort of encapsulation of both words.

Comment: Ah no, it's not two words, it actually has an Underscore in between the two.

Comment: You may want to edit your question then. Also the second table in the first query is PROJECTS whilst in the second query it is PROJECT, which could be an issue.

Comment: You can actually get FileMaker to show you the internal SQL error if you encapsulate the query in a Let statement. Put your ExecuteSQL function result in a variable and return the result or error like this: IF ( Query = "?" ; "" ; Query ). More here: https://www.teamdf.com/blogs/unlocking-hidden-error-messages-in-the-executesql-function/

Comment: @yanman1234 Ah that was a typo I missed when writing the question. is not in my actual query.

Comment: @AndreasT Oh that's really cool, I had no idea that was possible. I'm going to try that out. Thanks!

Comment: Based on your queries it seems PROCESSED_SAMPLES are causing an issue then. You could try joining just that table with one of the others to see if you still get an error or not, then go from there.

Comment: So I actually recently tried joining the PROJECTS table to the PROCESSED_SAMPLES table which did not work. They both have a user_id. Maybe I should do a left join on projects and then join with the user table at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I think, your last query will not work - FileMaker has limited support for subqueries. Second query should work.

You are missing AND between your WHERE parmeters.

> GROUP BY STATUS

Check if this column exists in more than one table. If it is the case, add table specifier.

> ORDER BY c DESC
>
> JOIN PROCESSED SAMPLES C

You have two different things assigned to the same alias - "c". I suspect that the second assignment overwrites the first so the ORDER BY tries to sort by a table object instead of the column.